# Jquery for each not showing callback function inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute a callback function which is inside object while iterating through for each loop of jquery.

Lets say I have this object

```js
var myVar = {
  firstObj: {
    name: 'something'
  },
  myFunc: function(value) {
    if (value != 'me') {
      return 'Name should be me';
    }
    return true;
  }
};

//I am iterating it in this way
$.each(myVar, function(index, object) {
  console.info(index, object);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to see it in **console.info()** but its not seems to be appearing

Comment: It seems to work in the snippet

Comment: I have converted your code to snippet, Whats not working?

Comment: Works fine in the code snippet.  What exactly are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Do you mean you want to actually call `myFunc`?

Comment: Don't know why still console.info() not showing callback function to me.Other elements are appearing. I am wondering whether this has to do anything with jquery version or something.

Comment: I don't understand why you're each-ing. You have an object method. Call it where you need to?

Comment: I want to iterate it and execute as I need to do it in order. Some elements are objects and some are callback functions

Comment: You can check if the object in your each is of type function `if (typeof object == "function "){object(value);}` this will cal your function if the object you are iterating over is of type function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your snippet to execute the function in your object

```js
var myVar = {
  firstObj: {
    name: 'something'
  },
  myFunc: function(value) {
    if (value != 'me') {
      return 'Name should be me';
    }
    return true;
  }
};

//I am iterating it in this way
$.each(myVar, function(index, object) {
  if (typeof object == "function"){
      console.log(object('me'));
      console.log(object('not me'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for your answers. What I posted was a sample code.
I did not notice a silly thing and lost some points here.
Below is the code close to what I have been trying.

```
var myVar = {
            ruleOne     : {},
            checkName   : function(value) {
                if(value != 'me') {
                    return 'name should be me';
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
var collect = {rules: {}};      
$.each(myVar, function(index, object) {
    if($.isFunction(object)) {
        collect.rules[index]   = object;
    } else {
        collect.rules[index]   = {message: 'rule one message'};
    }
});
$.each(collect.rules, function(index, object) {
    console.info(index, object);
    if($.isFunction(object)) {
        return object('me');
    } else {
        // this function was making it go out of iteration and not printing further elements
        return checkRuleOne();
    }
});

function checkRuleOne() {
    //some logic returning false
    return false;
}
```